# What does "180TB per year workload" mean on the WD Red 12TB

Tags: linux, hard-drive, nas

I'm asking because badblocks will write the full capacity of the disk 4 times and read it 4 times. Would that mean a hit of 96TB on my HD workload or a hit of 48TB?

I read that HD workload ratings started to be used because the higher capacity hard drives use a much more intense writing process. In that case, it should only apply to writes. Or is WD saying 180TB/year workload for a typical use case with a 2 to 1 read/write mix?

https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/05/03/when_did_hard_drives_get_workload_rate_limits/

Comment: Sounds like a way to limit warranties, also sounds like bullshit for spinning drives..

Comment: Backblaze is a cloud storage vendor that releases studies on their hard drive reliability... see https://www.backblaze.com/blog/hard-drive-stats-for-2017/ .  While that study doesn't explicitly say how much writing is done to individual disks or in aggregate, you might find useful info on Backblazes' site or by contacting them.  You might also ask WD.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage Backblaze is an indispensable resource, my concern wasn't failure rates, but voiding the warranty by using the drives inappropriately.

Comment: WD will probably have some definitive info on what voids the warranty.  Opening the case definitely does, making physical changes to the electronics definitely does, maybe operating too hot too long, or water entering the case.  I don't know if an HD vendor ever turned away a warranty claim based on writing usage, but the vendor is the right place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [@tonny's](https://superuser.com/users/83250/tonny) suggestion, here's what I got from customer support:

> Workload of 180TB/y is combined read/write. No
>   information regarding Read/write ratios is available.

This seems like the marketing department running away with an engineering limitation to squeeze more money by pushing WD Gold's with their 550TB/yr rating.

That's not to say that they aren't different... the controllers of the WD Red's might use cheaper capacitors/resistors, which I think is legal as long as you're upfront about it... and by giving us that low workload limit, they are technically being upfront. Like [@sprbrn](https://superuser.com/users/39436/sprbrn) said, the controllers typically fail first, which is really strange as that's the easiest thing to build to last.

Answer (score 3):

According to the definition provided in Western Digital datasheets (e.g. [this one](https://documents.westerndigital.com/content/dam/doc-library/en_us/assets/public/western-digital/product/data-center-drives/general-docs/data-sheet-ultrastar-sata-series-2879-810017.pdf) ):

> Workload Rate is defined as the amount of user data transferred to or
> from the hard drive. Workload Rate is annualized. Workload Rate will
> vary depending on your hardware and software components and
> configurations.

According to the [definition provided by Seagate](https://www.seagate.com/gb/en/support/kb/annualized-workload-rate-005902en/):

> Annualized Workload Rate = (Lifetime Writes + Lifetime Reads) * (8,760
> / Lifetime Power On Hours)
>
> where 8,760 are the number of hours in a year.

The importance of this magnitude stems from the fact that Disk drives are specifically designed to perform to up to certain levels of Workload Rates.  These are called **Workload Rate Limits (WRL)**.  To make a long story short, if the amount of data read and/or write to/from the hard drive in a year surpasses the WRL the reliability of your disk will begin to decline.

If you want to dive into some more details, i suggest reading: [How HDD Workload Impacts TCO](https://blackboxparadoxblog.files.wordpress.com/2016/10/how-hdd-workload-impacts-tco-tp648-2-1309us.pdf).

**One last thought:** Of course, in case one is thinking of buying a new hard drive, they should bear in mind that manufacturers may not follow the same methodology when it comes to gathering the data used to calculate the drive's WRL. So comparing hard drives in terms of WRL, is (probably) safer when conducted among hard drives from the same manufacturer.

Comment: To anyone reading this, I recommend reading page 3 of the document linked above.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a generally accepted standard that defines "per year workload".
Every manufacturer uses its own terminology and definitions of what that terminology means. Some count reads and writes, some count only writes, some use a "typical" mix of reads and writes (for whatever ratio they consider typical).
So you will have to ask WD support what they really mean with that.

Answer (score 0):

That "per year" - what does it mean? I can write 15x 12TB per year? For three or ten or twenty years? I guess that the warranty is limited to one or two years, so you get maximum 360TB write warranty if this is in the EU. After that you're on your own. It could very well be that you can do that ten times with losing some sectors, but nothing really bad.

The problem is probably not the disk, but the controller. How much data can it handle? In my experience, the controller is often the first to fail.

If you would use this disk to backup a 1TB database daily, you can keep 12 backups before it writes over the oldest. This would result in 365TB data in one year. In this simple example, each sector would be overwritten about 30 times. That can't be too much for the disk. Each sector should be able to handle thousands of writes.

It comes down to statistics. Only a few people will do this daily 1TB backup. Most will do only a few (thousand small) files, so they have to find a way to give you an idea what it can handle.

Another way to think of this is how long it takes to transfer 12TB to that disk. I guess it's USB3 or internal SATA? Can your computer handle that full speed all day? How long does it take to transfer 180TB?